# Making a DuckDuckHack Instant Answer work on own site

Tags: javascript, html, css, duckduckgo

I'm trying to see whether it's possible to use the code from [DuckDuckHack](https://duckduckhack.com/) Instant Answers outside of the context of the main DuckDuckGo website. After all, an Instant Answer is mostly a standalone component that consists of some HTML, CSS and Javascript and should be relatively self-contained and reusable.

Since the DuckDuckHack project is in maintenance mode, it seems to be a bit difficult to obtain information: the Slack and Forum mentioned on the [Developer Guide](https://duckduckhack.gitbook.io/duckduckhack-docs/get-in-touch) have been disabled. I tried to find out whether other people tried to make Instant Answers work in other contexts, but I couldn't find anything. There are tutorials on writing Instant Answers, such as [this](https://www.perl.com/article/169/2015/4/20/Writing-DuckDuckGo-instant-answers-is-easy/) using Perl and the DuckPAN tools. I tried to get an existing Instant Answer to work using those tools but I failed to get it to work properly (not sure whether they are still maintained).

Since those tools seem to be a bit heavyweight, I thought it could be possible to bypass them completely and try to just use the HTML, CSS and JS from the Instant Answer directly.

I've given the [Calculator](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=1%2B1&t=h_&ia=calculator) a first shot. I identified the relevant source code in the [duckduckgo/zeroclickinfo-goodies](https://github.com/duckduckgo/zeroclickinfo-goodies) repository's directory [share/goodie/calculator](https://github.com/duckduckgo/zeroclickinfo-goodies/tree/master/share/goodie/calculator). The HTML seems to be in the `content.handlebars`, and then there's `calculator.css` and `calculator.js`. I created a [plain HTML file](https://github.com/sebkur/duckduckhack/blob/master/calculator/index.html), put the HTML from `content.handlebars` in there and included references to the CSS file and the JS file. At first, the CSS wouldn't work because the CSS rules don't apply without adding some more wrapper divs that can be easily found when inspecting the DuckDuckGo site with the calculator Instant Answer visible. After adding those wrapper divs, the calculator UI [appears more or less intact](https://sebkur.github.io/duckduckhack/calculator/). However the buttons of the UI do not work at all yet.

Looking at the Javascript console I get this error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: DDH is not defined
    at calculator.js:1
```

Apparently an object `DDH` is required by [calculator.js](https://github.com/duckduckgo/zeroclickinfo-goodies/blob/master/share/goodie/calculator/calculator.js), however I have no idea what that object should be and how I could create it.

Does anybody know how this `DDH` variable gets usually initialized or more generally how to make this work? Any reference to projects reusing the code from DuckDuckHack for their own sites would also be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I think the details of how the `DDH` object is put together might not be exposed through the open-source portion of DDG.

I've also made some attempts to repurpose some of the built-in DDG IA functionality (e.g. get programmatic access to the many, useful instant answers unavailable through their [API](https://duckduckgo.com/api)).

In the process, I cloned the [goodie repo](https://github.com/duckduckgo/zeroclickinfo-goodies) and poked around. The pattern seems to be that for most goodies the payload to be displayed is `DDH.<goodie>.content`. In my local copy of the `goodie` repo:

```
$ grep -rE 'DDH' ./lib/

./lib/DDG/Goodie/Conversions.pm:                    content => 'DDH.conversions.content'
./lib/DDG/Goodie/Conversions.pm:                content => 'DDH.conversions.content'
./lib/DDG/Goodie/Game2048.pm:                content => 'DDH.game2048.content'
./lib/DDG/Goodie/PublicDNS.pm:                list_content => 'DDH.public_dns.content',
./lib/DDG/Goodie/JsBeautifier.pm:                    content => 'DDH.js_beautifier.content'
./lib/DDG/Goodie/SassToCss.pm:                    content => 'DDH.sass_to_css.content'
./lib/DDG/Goodie/Constants.pm:                title_content => 'DDH.constants.title_content'
...
```

On the javascript side of things, you'd find the corresponding `.js` files in the `share/goodie` directory, as you did for the calculator goodie.

The `<goodie>.js` files seem to introduce `DDH.<goodie>` namespaces (typically right at the top of the file) and define `DDH.<goodie>.build` functions. This procedure is referenced in the [goodie-display docs](https://github.com/duckduckgo/duckduckhack-docs/blob/master/frontend-reference/setting-goodie-display.md) (see the section titled **Setting Goodie Display Options on the Front end** therein).

Nowhere in the docs, though, is it documented how the `content` property of `DDH.<goodie>` is put together. I cloned the [docs repo](https://github.com/duckduckgo/duckduckhack-docs) and grepped for `DDH`, revealing nothing to that effect.

None of the `.js` files in the `share/goodie` folder of the [goodie repo](https://github.com/duckduckgo/zeroclickinfo-goodies), though, seem to give a clue as to how `DDH.<goodie>.content` is assembled either. Indeed, some of those `.js` files do not even contain the string `content`. For a listing of all `share*.js` files that *do* contain the string `content`, I did (in the local copy of the `goodie` repo):

```
$ find ./share -name "*.js" |xargs grep -l 'content'

./share/goodie/countdown/countdown.js
./share/goodie/text_converter/text_converter.js
```

The other `.js` files do not contain that string at all..

**Edit**

On the other hand though, I see you did manage to get the [calculator](https://sebkur.github.io/duckduckhack/calculator/) going with some modifications to the `.js` [file](https://github.com/sebkur/duckduckhack/blob/master/calculator/calculator.js) (e.g. by inserting that missing `DDH` namespace).